# Shopify Graphql Product Media Sources

Tags: graphql, shopify

I'm writing graphql query to fetch a Shopify product, and I cannot figure out how to get the product's media sources. The only available fields in the [MediaConnection!](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/object/media?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07) according to the docs and GraphiQl are `alt`, `mediaContentType`, and `previewImage`.

Simplified query below:

```
{
  productByHandle(handle: ${handle}) {
    media(first: 5) {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          alt
          mediaContentType
          previewImage {
            altText
            originalSrc
            transformedSrc(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 400, crop: CENTER, preferredContentType: JPG)
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

This is fine if I don't have any video in the media, the `previewImage` will suffice, but, what if the `mediaContentType` is video? How do I get the sources of the [Video](https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/object/video?api%5Bversion%5D=2020-07)?

Comment: In [this help article](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-product-media-with-admin-api#retrieving-media-objects) it shows handling video different from images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @JHeth pointing me in the direction of this [help article][1], I was able to figure this out. I needed to use fragments.

```
{
  productByHandle(handle: ${handle}) {
    media(first: 5) {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          alt
          mediaContentType
          previewImage {
            altText
            originalSrc
            transformedSrc(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 400, crop: CENTER, preferredContentType: JPG)
          }
          ... on Video {
            sources {
            format
            height
            mimeType
            url
            width
            }
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
      }
    }   
  }
}

  [1]: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-product-media-with-admin-api#retrieving-media-objects
```